# Why does the .constructor change when you change the .prototype? (see code)

Tags: javascript

Here's the code that explains the question further:

```
function MyConstructor() {}
 var myobject = new MyConstructor();
 myobject.constructor == MyConstructor;     // true
```

```
function MyConstructor() {}
 MyConstructor.prototype = {};
 var myobject = new MyConstructor(); 
 myobject.constructor == MyConstructor;  // false
```

So, why is the second block **false**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `constructor` of the created object changes because the `constructor` of its prototype changes. This is why you generally shouldn't overwrite the prototype. If you do, make sure to set it back later:

```
function MyConstructor() {}
MyConstructor.prototype = {};
MyConstructor.prototype.constructor = MyConstructor;
…
var myobject = new MyConstructor(); 
myobject.constructor == MyConstructor;  // false
```

Comment: +1 I recommend extending the prototype with an appropriate function instead.

Comment: thanks for the great answ--- whoah, you're 14 years old????! :) keep up the good work!

Comment: @pimvdb: Thanks for telling me about this in the first place :)